# Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-postgresql, pg

I am using the Ruby on Rails 3.1 pre version. I like to use PostgreSQL, but the problem is installing the `pg` gem. It gives me the following error:

```
$ gem install pg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/u/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/u/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    Gem files will remain installed in /home/u/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/pg-0.11.0 for inspection.
    Results logged to /home/u/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/pg-0.11.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: can you prove that you have pg installed?

Answer (score 1552, accepted):

It looks like in Ubuntu that header is part of the [`libpq-dev` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/i386/libpq-dev/filelist) (at least in the following Ubuntu versions: 
[11.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29) (Natty Narwhal), [10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) (Lucid Lynx), [11.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_11.10_.28Oneiric_Ocelot.29) (Oneiric Ocelot), [12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin), [14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) and [18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_(Bionic_Beaver)) (Bionic Beaver)):

```
...
/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h
...
```

So try installing `libpq-dev` or its equivalent for your OS:

- For Ubuntu/Debian systems: `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`
- On [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) (RHEL) systems: `yum install postgresql-devel`
- For Mac [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29): `brew install postgresql`
- For Mac [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) PostgreSQL: `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql[version number]/bin/pg_config`
- For [OpenSuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE): `zypper in postgresql-devel`
- For [ArchLinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux): `pacman -S postgresql-libs`

Comment: didn't work for me on ubuntu 11.04 `durrantm@castleLinux2011:~/Dropbox_not_syncd/webs/3/linker$ gem install libpq-dev
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'libpq-dev' (>= 0) in any repository
durrantm@castleLinux2011:~/Dropbox_not_syncd/webs/3/linker$ 
`

Comment: If you then are required to have a javascript library installed...
gem install 'execjs' and 
gem install 'therubyracer'

Comment: @TravisR: Thanks for the update, I just turned this into a community wiki to make it easier for everyone to keep it up to date.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.10, I am not able to install pg gem after installing libpq-dev

Comment: @vedarthk: What does "not able" mean? Perhaps a new question with the install logs would get you the help you need.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes I have posted the question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/14477825/1277376

Comment: Works with Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Comment: In `Mac OS X`, get `homebrew` from http://brew.sh , then `brew install postgres` to install PostgresQL and its header files.

Comment: Works like a charm in `centOS 6.5`

Comment: Please revise your answer to include `apt-get install postgres-server-dev-{pg.version}`

Your answer no longer works with postgresql 9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 

See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28837453/75194

Comment: @RyanRauh: Can you submit an edit? I'm not using Ubuntu right now so I'm not really qualified to say much here.

Comment: I just had a probelm with this because I was confusing g and q. to be clear, the package wanted is `libpq-dev` with a Q not a G

Comment: I tried to do that on Ubuntu 14.04 but it gave me this: " libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 9.3.4-1) but 9.3.10-0ubuntu0.14.04 is to be installed.

Comment: But then when I try to install libpq5, it says "libpq5 is already the newest version. Same for PostgreSQL."

Comment: PostgreSQL version is: psql --version: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.10. PostgreSQL 9.3.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-server-dev-9.3 : Depends: libpq-dev (>= 9.3~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @MichaelLafayette I don't have Ubuntu set up anywhere right now so I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: While I executed the command : sudo apt-get install libpq-dev, I get a response - "Unable to locate package".

So I execute sudo apt-get update, then executed "sudo apt-get install libpq-dev". Finally it successfully installed.

Comment: Why do gem designers rely on implicit, undocumented, globally installed dependencies, and make no attempt to check for their existence before installing the gem?

Comment: @AndyRay But they are checking for dependencies, that's what "checking for pg_config" and "checking for libpq-fe.h" are about. There's no way to check if the PostgreSQL development stuff is installed without, well, installing some scripts that look for the standard PostgreSQL dev tools (such as `pg_config` or the header file). Same thing happens when you need anything that isn't packaged inside a gem.

Comment: Ubuntu/Debian systems solution valid for Raspbian v9.9 on Raspberry Pi devices.

Comment: I tried the same steps but still getting error in Redhat:

Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/ext
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20190924-18624-nckmb.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***

Comment: This worked for me, I already had installed Postgres, and I just needed to execute `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` then `bundle install` and the error disappeared. Thanks

Answer (score 241):

On **macOS** (previously **Mac OS X** and **OS X**), use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install the proper headers:

```
brew install postgresql
```

and then running

```
gem install pg
```

should work.

Alternatively, instead of installing the whole `postgresql`, you can `brew install libpq` and export the correct `PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` as explained in the 'Caveats' section

Comment: Does this cause any problems if you're also using Postgres.app?

Comment: @iconoclast I use Postgres.app to run a db instance so having the `pg` gem just allows you to hook your Rails app up to your local Postgres.app instance

Comment: For me after run `brew install postgressql` i run `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg` and works fine.

Comment: Alternatively, just running `brew install libpqxx` on mac OSX suffices

Comment: @RicardoSaporta `libpqxx` installs `postgresql` as dependency, so it is essentially the same as `brew install postgresql`

Comment: Instead of installing the whole `postgresql`, you can `brew install libpq` and export the correct `PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` as explained in the 'Caveats' section.

Comment: This also sorted it for me on Ubuntu 20.04 using Linuxbrew. `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` kept failing because of some other dependency

Comment: As someone who's just been hired to work with Ruby/Rails for the first time... Are there many more issues like this? Where a build requires a **database** installation to run? Do Ruby builds keep breaking for random reasons like this?

Comment: @iconoclast I can confirm this does not cause problems with Postgres.app. I've installed Postgres.app and done 'brew install postgres' on two Macs now, in order to get around the problem of pg not installing due to missing headers. Both times worked great, and allow successful bundle install or gem install pg. No need for specifying --with-pg-config, that was a red herring for me.

Answer (score 130):

I had also tried doing `gem install libpq-dev`, but I received this error:

```
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

However I found that installing with `sudo apt-get` (which I try to avoid using with Ruby on Rails) worked, i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
# or
apt-get install postgres-server-dev-{pg.version}
# for postgresql 9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04
```

then I was able to do

```
gem install pg
```

without issues.

Comment: Right, the Ruby pg gem wraps the usual PostgreSQL C libraries that come with the Ubuntu/Debian/... `libpq-dev` package.

Answer (score 57):

I could solve this in another way. I didn't find the library on my system. Thus I installed it using an app from PostgreSQL main website. In my case (OS X) I found the file under `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/include/` once the installation was over. You may also have the file somewhere else depending on your system if you already have PostgreSQL installed.

Thanks to this link on [how to add an additional path for gem installation](http://marsorange.com/archives/gem-install-a-non-standard-include-directory), I could point the gem to the lib with this command:

```
export CONFIGURE_ARGS="with-pg-include=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/include/"
gem install pg
```

After that, it works, because it now knows where to find the missing library. Just replace the path with the right location for your libpq-fe.h

Comment: David's solution worked for me. I tracked libpq-fe.h to '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/include' and used the export command with said path, followed by the 'gem install pg' and the gem installed successfully.

Comment: Thanks for this, worked for me, using: `export CONFIGURE_ARGS="with-pg-include=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.1/include/"`

Comment: Using Postgresql 9.3 on CentOS 6 I solved this by symlinking the `pg_*` scripts into the $PATH like so: `ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/p* /usr/local/bin`. I installed postgres 9.3 like so: `yum install http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm && yum install postgresql93 postgresql93-contrib postgresql93-server postgresql93-devel`

Comment: you can also write as `gem install pg -- with-pg-include=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/include/`

Comment: Better yet, use `export CONFIGURE_ARGS="with-pg-config=/path/to/postgres/bin/pg_config"`. The `pg_config` executable will be called to get all the required compiler and linker options — you can run it yourself to see them.

Comment: David's version didn't work for installing an old version of the gem (0.21), but @skozin's instruction did. Thank you!

Comment: this worked perfectly for me on ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Thank you!

Answer (score 33):

> Can't find the libpq-fe.h header

i had success on **CentOS 7.0.1406** running the following commands:

```
~ % psql --version # => psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.1
yum install libpqxx-devel
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config
```

**Alternatively**, you can configure bundler to always install `pg` with these options (helpful for running bundler in deploy environments),

- `bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config`

Comment: very helpful, thanks. Just to add a note regarding bundle config... you must run this command while logged-in as the user who will be running the subsequent bundle command. The bundler config is stored in ~/.bundle/config, so it will not be found if you run bundle config while logged-in as root, but bundler is being run by (e.g. with capistrano) the 'deploy' user.

Comment: **bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config** solve i for me on Centos 7

Comment: ***bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_config***  if you are using postgresql10

Comment: For postgres 12 and above I had to do `yum install libpq5-devel`

Answer (score 26):

For [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6.4,

```
yum install postgresql-devel
gem install pg
```

worked well!

Comment: Using macports, `sudo port install postgresql-devel`.

Answer (score 19):

Just for the record:

Ruby on Rails 4 application in OS X with PostgresApp (in this case 0.17.1 version needed - kind of an old project):

```
gem install pg -v '0.17.1' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
```

Comment: Works great if you're using the wonderful [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com). For Postgres 10, I used the path `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10/bin/pg_config`

Answer (score 18):

It is only issue of missing `libpq-fe.h`

On ubuntu we just need to run:
`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

Above command will install a NEW package `libpq-dev` and after that you can again execute `bundle install` to resume your bundle installation.

Comment: worked like a charm! `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev &&  cd project-directory && bundle install` .

Answer (score 16):

On Mac OS X run like this:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=***/path/to/pg_config***
```

`***/path/to/pg_config***` is path to pg_config

Comment: Upvoted. I installed Postgresql via EnterpriseDB's [grapihcal installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx). Then I need to find out the pg-config path by `sudo find / -name "pg_config"`, then do `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_config` using the path I have just found out.

Answer (score 14):

In my case it was package `postgresql-server-dev-8.4` (I am on [Ubuntu 11.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29) (Natty Narwhal), 64 bits).

Answer (score 13):

For **MacOS** without installing PostgreSQL server:

```
brew install libpq
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config="/usr/local/Cellar/libpq/9.6.6/bin/pg_config"
```

Answer (score 13):

My solution for Fedora 30:

```
sudo dnf install /usr/include/libpq-fe.h
```

Comment: I would love to buy you a beer sometime. This is the ONLY thing that worked in Centos 7/8 after hours struggling with it

Comment: worked for me on fedora 35 .

thanks aaron bro. 

wonder how you figured it out.

Comment: Worked for me on Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.0. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The right answer for Mac users with Postgres.app is to build against the `libpq` provided with that package. For example, with the 9.4 release (current as of this writing), all you need is:

```
export CONFIGURE_ARGS="with-pg-include=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/include"
gem install pg
```

This will keep your `pg` gem in sync with exactly the version of PostgreSQL you have installed. Installing something from Homebrew is a waste in this case.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue on Amazon Linux. I could find the header `libpq-fe.h`, but somehow it didn't work.

It came from the different versions of the packages that were installed through the different users on the machine. PostgreSQL 9.2 and PostgreSQL 9.3 were installed. So, make sure of your PostgreSQL version before including the libraries.

For me, the magic command line was:

```
sudo yum install postgresql93 postgresql93-server postgresql93-libs postgresql93-contrib postgresql93-devel
```

Source: *[An almost idiot's guide to install PostgreSQL 9.3, PostGIS 2.1 and pgRouting with Yum](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/329-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.3,-PostGIS-2.1-and-pgRouting-with-Yum.html)*

Comment: After installing libraries... do a clean up: "make distclean", "make clean", "./configure" and start compiling!

Answer (score 8):

A more general answer for any Debian-based distribution (which includes Ubuntu) is the following. First, install the `apt-file` package running as root:

```
apt-get install apt-file
```

This allows you to search for packages containing a file. Then, update its database using

```
apt-file update
```

(this can be run as normal user). Then, look for the missing header using:

```
apt-file search libpq-fe.h
```

On my machine, this gives:

```
libpq-dev: /usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h
postgres-xc-server-dev: /usr/include/postgres-xc/server/gtm/libpq-fe.h
```

There you go !

Comment: "libpq-dev: /usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h" is present whereas "postgres-xc-server-dev: /usr/include/postgres-xc/server/gtm/libpq-fe.h" is not present ? what am I missing ?

Comment: File contents may have changed. This looks like there was a private copy of libpq-fe.h in the postgres-... package. In any case, the libXXX-dev is the one you're looking for if you want to compile things.

Comment: So once found, what is the next step?

Comment: apt-get install the_package_you_found

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu, install the "libpq-dev" to get rid of this issue.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: If it is not enough, add `sudo apt-get install postgresql` before `libpq-dev`

Answer (score 8):

On debian bullseye, none of the existing answers solved the issue for me.

In case it helps someone with the same configuration as mine:

1. Use PostgreSQL's apt repository: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt
2. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (upgrade PostgreSQL from v13 to v14)
3. `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`
4. `gem install pg` or `bundle install`

Answer (score 7):

On Fedora 32, I managed to solve this same issue by installing `libpq5-devel` specifically.

If you install postgresql from the official repository, you will have several versions that won't fix the problem, so it's really a matter of trying out which one it needs.

Comment: Doesn't let me edit your answer, you missed a letter, it should be `libpq5-devel`. It helped though, thanks.

Comment: I swear I had noticed that and fixed it but I guess I just thought about it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

Solved on **MacOS M1**:

```
brew install libpq
```

Then I put in my PATH

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

And:

```
gem install pg
```

Comment: after echo, you need also to source ~/.zshrc

Comment: works great on my new laptop running MacOS Ventura 13.4. yes, close the window and restart the shell in a new window.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue with Postgresql 9.6. I was able to fix it by doing:

```
brew upgrade postgresql@9.6
brew link postgresql@9.6 --force
gem install pg
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on Mac OS, but I installed the PostgreSQL gem easily by using the following in a terminal:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

(I installed PostgreSQL first with `brew install postgresql`.)

Answer (score 5):

I found this answer, and it was the only one that worked for me (Mac OS) - after researching for about two days:

```
$ sudo su

$ env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.11.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for pg-0.11.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for pg-0.11.0...
```

See Stack Overflow question *[Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq)*.

Comment: Thank you, this was only one that worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

I recently upgraded to [Mac OS X v10.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite) and was having difficulty building the `pg` gem.

The error reported was the typical:

```
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

My solution was to `gem uninstall pg` and then `bundle update pg` to replace the gem with the latest. I did run `brew update; brew upgrade` after the Yosemite install to get the latest versions of packages I had installed previously.

Answer (score 5):

On a Mac, I solved it using this code:

```
gem install pg -v '0.18.4' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by creating symlink on MacOS Ventura

if postgresql already installed;

```
brew link postgresql@12 --force
```

This command will give directory path as below

```
If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@12/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

you need to add zsh or bash_profile to your computer, whichever you are using

Answer (score 4):

I am running Postgres.app on a Mac and I had to

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
```

first. Then

```
bundle install
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same error with postgres installed through asdf. The pg-config solutions didn't work for me. Instead I had to locate the postgres include folder which contains the file and run the command with the `--with-pg-include` flag

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/<path>/.asdf/installs/postgres/<version>/include
```

Comment: Note: `/<path>/.asdf/installs/postgres/<version>` is returned by `asdf where postgres`

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it working on MacOS Ventura with Apple Silicon using

```
brew install libpq
brew install postgresql

gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.7/bin/pg_config
```

Check and replace `/postgresql@14/14.7/` with your version.

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS,I installed `libpq-dev package` using below command

```
yum install postgresql-devel
```

Executing `gem install pg` returned the same error as "`No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config`".

Installing the gem as below solved my problem

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-x.x/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 3):

The location of `libpq-fe.h` depends on where your PostgreSQL install is (which depends on how you installed it). Use `locate` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_%28Unix%29) to find the `libpq-fe.h` file on your machine. If it exists, it will be in the `include` directory of your PostgreSQL install.

```
$ locate libpq-fe.h
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/include/libpq-fe.h
```

The `bin` directory, which contains `pg_config`, will be in the same directory as the `include` directory. As the error suggests, use the --with-pg-config option to install the gem:

```
$ gem install pg --with-pg-config="/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config"
```

Note that you may need to run `updatedb` if you have never used `locate` or if you haven't updated since installing PostgreSQL.

Comment: Without a `--` before the `--with-pg-config=...` I get an error: _ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption) invalid option: --with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config)_

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 20.04, I already had libpq5:amd64 version 13.2-1.pgdg20.04+1. Now when I tried to install libpq-dev from apt repository, I was receiving

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 13.2-1.pgdg20.04+1 is to be installed
```

I grabbed the deb from `http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/postgresql-13/libpq-dev_13.2-1_amd64.deb` and did the following:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/libpq-dev
dpkg-deb -R libpq-dev_13.2-1_amd64.deb /tmp/libpq-dev
sed -i 's|= 13.2-1|= 13.2-1.pgdg20.04+1|' /tmp/libpq-dev/DEBIAN/control
dpkg-deb -b /tmp/libpq-dev /tmp/libpq-dev-new.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/libpq-dev-new.deb
```

I have been using the gem happily after that. No additional installs or anything.

Answer (score 3):

For alpine, please use below to fix the error

```
apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

On FreeBSD (9.1) the necessary package is /usr/ports/database/postgresql-server* which when installed will also install the required header file that makes the gem install of "pg" fail. This answer here helped me find the solution but the difference in package names required a bit of searching.

Hopefully this helps someone avoid a bit of head scratching when searching for the "-dev" package on a FreeBSD system!

Answer (score 2):

On [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) 7.0, 64-bit (Wheezy), just run:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

After you successfully installed libpq-dev, run:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 2):

Under CentOS 6.5 (Squeeze) I created a file:

```
$ sudo touch /etc/profile.d/psql.sh
```

with content:

```
pathmunge /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin
```

Note here, you should set your PostgreSQL path with the pg_config file. You can find this with the command:

```
$ sudo find / -iname pg_config
```

Save the file:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/ruby.sh
```

and try to execute your command again.

Note: Anytime you change the [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) configuration - changing the profile.d configuration - you should reload Bash.

Comment: How did you install postgres? I symlinked the `pg_*` scripts into the path like so: `ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/p* /usr/local/bin`. After that I didn’t need any additional scripts or environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this problem, but not using the previously described methods.

Using `brew install postgresql`, I find out that it had already been installed, but not linked.

1. Find out where PostgreSQL is installed, and delete it,
2. Then `brew install postgresql` again,
3. `brew link postgresql`
4. `gem install pg`

Comment: "brew link --force postgresql" worked for me but befor that i have to run 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.4/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

I solved this installing the 'postgresql-common' package. This package provides the `pg_config` binary which is most likely what you were missing.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, and this fixed it for me:

```
gem install do_postgres -- --with-pgsql-server-dir=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS --with-pgsql-server-include=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/include/server
```

Source:

https://gist.github.com/oisin/6562181

Answer (score 1):

Only uninstalling (sudo apt-get purge) libpq-dev and re-installing  it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

On [OS X 10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks), I `brew-installed postgresql`, and I then had to `rvm reinstall` my Ruby. I am happy now :)

Answer (score 1):

For `AltLinux` the package `postgresqlx.x-devel` (in my case `postgresql9.5-devel`) must be installed:

```
apt-get install postgresql9.5-devel
```

Comment: You can also install specific versions with yum - yum install postgresqlxx-devel e.g yum install postgresql94-devel

Answer (score 1):

I just had this on OSX running brew and `postgres@9.4`.

My fix was this:

```
CONFIGURE_ARGS="with-pg-include=/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.4/include/" bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS X just install https://postgresapp.com/ and follow steps for command line section and ruby

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d &&
echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```

Then

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

Comment: I found the same answer here for the top code section above: https://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html under 

"Configure your $PATH" 

then all I had to do was open a new terminal and 

```bundle install```.

I'm on an M1 Mac.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X and [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) the `-devel` package for PostgreSQL is not required any more. Installing the `pg` gem works as follows:

```
~ > sudo port install postgresql-devel
...
Error: postgresql-devel has been replaced by postgresql91; please install that port instead
~ > gem install pg -v '0.17.1' -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql95/bin/pg_config
```

See also [this post](https://github.com/codeforamerica/ohana-api/wiki/Installing-PostgreSQL-with-MacPorts-on-OS-X).

Comment: `port select --set postgresql postgresql96` or any other version you installed to active symlinks including `pg_config`

Answer (score 0):

On Arch Linux you will need to install [postgresql-libs](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/postgresql-libs/files/):

```
sudo pacman -Syu postgresql-libs
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Make sure postgress is installed in your system ( If it's already installed and you can run postgress server on your machine move to step (2)

```
apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib (sol - fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory)
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev (required to install postgress below)
sudo gem install pg
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Step 2) Some of the c++ files are trying to access `libpq-fe.h` directly and cant find. So we need to manually search every such file and replace `libpq-fe.h` with `postgresql/libpq-fe.h`

Command for searching all occurrences of `libpq-fe.h` in all dir and subdir is `grep -rnw ./  -e 'libpq-fe.h'`

3) Go to All the file listed by command run in step 2 and manually change `libpq-fe.h` with `postgresql/libpq-fe.h`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all solutions but only works below command

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, this seemed to work for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev libpqxx-dev libpq-fe-dev libpq-dev 
sudo gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/include/postgresql/pg_config --with-pg-include=/usr/include/postgresql/
```

Comment: And `ls /usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config` can be used to check the files are there to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem too. I tried many of the answers above and none worked.
What finally worked was to check brew was working fine (`brew doctor`) and to restart the terminal.

Then the error as gone.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed the same error by doing a Ruby reinstall via rvm:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Comment: it helped to recover back to initial ruby distribution from rvm but not fixing the problem.