# rails install pg - Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header

Tags: c, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3, pg

```
$ sudo bundle install
```

Result

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.2.8) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.8) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.8) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.11) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.8) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.8) 
Using activeresource (3.2.8) 
Using bundler (1.2.1) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.8) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.3) 
Installing pg (0.14.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.14.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.14.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am make `$ gem install pg -v '0.14.1'` But this is not help

My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#gem 'rails', '3.0.9'

#gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.6', :group => :development


gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'


gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'taps'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'


#group :production do
  #gem 'pg'
#end
#group :development do
  #gem 'sqlite3'
#end
```

gem_make.out

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
```

mkmf.log

```
find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- yes

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -E -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC    conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:1:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

Help me please. Thank you.

Sorry for this text.
Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem)

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Just make this

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: I tried to do that on Ubuntu 14.04 but it gave me this:     " libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 9.3.4-1) but 9.3.10-0ubuntu0.14.04 is to be installed "

Comment: But then when I try to install libpq5, it says "libpq5 is already the newest version."

Comment: PostgreSQL version is: psql --version: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.10. PostgreSQL 9.3.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit

Comment: Brilliant! The application I was compiling also needed the path to `libpq-fe.h` to be specified explicitly, with `--with-cflags=-I/usr/include/postgresql`, in case anyone else encounters the same.

Comment: For those of you wondering what libpq-dev means: It contains a minimal set of `PostgreSQL`_ binaries and headers requried for building 3rd-party applications for `PostgreSQL`_.

Comment: for Amazon linux, <code>yum install libpqxx-devel</code> fixes the issue

Comment: This was what ended up working for me, or at least the Mac version of it, which is `brew install libpq`. I then also had to `brew link --force libpq` to get the `gem install pg` to finish successfully.

Comment: In Ubuntu, in C++, you may want to use `#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>` instead of `#include <libpq-fe.h>`.

Answer (score 92):

This is answered in [Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem)

Depending on your environment:

- **Mac:** `brew install postgresql`
- **Ubuntu**: `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`
- **RHEL**: `yum install postgresql-devel`
- **Alpine**: `apk add postgresql-dev`

Then run `gem install pg` again

Comment: I tried to do that on Ubuntu 14.04 but it gave me this: " libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 9.3.4-1) but 9.3.10-0ubuntu0.14.04 is to be installed "

Comment: But then when I try to install libpq5, it says "libpq5 is already the newest version." Same for PostgreSQL

Comment: PostgreSQL version is: psql --version: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.10. PostgreSQL 9.3.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit

Comment: Hey Michael, I'm not sure I can answer your question because I'm not familiar with Ubuntu, but you may want to check out Michael Durrant's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8887801/2484523

Comment: Worked on Red Hat EL7.  I was getting the header file missing during a Perl install of DBD::Pg.

Comment: This is the answer for a CentOS droplet on Digital Ocean. `postgresql-devel` needs to be installed.

Comment: On CentOS6 'sudo yum install libpq*' installed the correct dependencies for me to gem install pg successfully.

Comment: For those of you experiencing this but also see "libpq5 is already the newest version." when you try to install, try `sudo apt-get remove libpq-dev` and then installing it again. Worked for me.

Comment: Note: If you installed the postgres app directly, you should instead run `brew install libpq`

Answer (score 21):

- SO: **Ubuntu**
- Language Programming: **C**

`$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

In my case I was putting the directory path wrong. So:

From: `gcc -o lib_version lib_version.c -I/usr/include/postgresql -lpq -std=c99`

To: `gcc -o lib_version lib_version.c -I /usr/include/postgresql -lpq -std=c99`

GL

Comment: this one is worked for me for postgreSQL kali installation

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

1. brew install postgresql
2. gem install pg
3. bundle install

Answer (score 17):

On Fedora/RHEL systems this did the trick:

```
sudo yum install libpqxx-devel
```

Comment: Why it says : No package libpqxx-devel available.

Comment: yum list libpq* followed by yum install libpqxx-devel.x86_64

Answer (score 10):

For [Alpine Linux](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=libpq-fe.h&path=&name=postgresql-dev&repo=main&arch=armhf), you can add `libpq-fe.h` with:

```
apk add postgresql-dev
```

Answer (score 8):

For Amazon Linux (AWS):

```
sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

then run your command again

Answer (score 5):

On Mac OS X run like this:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=***/path/to/pg_config***
```

`***/path/to/pg_config***` is path to pg_config

Comment: how do we find the path to `pg_config`, doing `where pg_config` returns `pg_conf` not found.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with a Jenkins server on Amazon AMI.

```
$ pg_config | grep VERSION
VERSION = PostgreSQL 9.4.9
```

Then depending on which version you need you can install the required lib

```
$ sudo yum list postgresql* | grep devel
postgresql92-devel.x86_64               9.2.18-1.59.amzn1          @amzn-main
postgresql94-devel.x86_64               9.4.9-1.67.amzn1           @amzn-main
postgresql8-devel.x86_64                8.4.20-5.52.amzn1          amzn-main
postgresql93-devel.x86_64               9.3.14-1.62.amzn1          amzn-main
postgresql95-devel.x86_64               9.5.4-1.71.amzn1           amzn-main
```

Then you can just install the corresponding version, in my case for version 9.4:

```
sudo yum install postgresql94-devel
```

Comment: Ah! Excellent. The specific version (9.6) was my roadblock on AMI as well.

Answer (score 4):

This was happening me using capistrano while deploying my app in a centos7 distro. Apparently gem is requiring some header files which can be resolved installing the right development package.

I fixed it by running `sudo yum search postgres | grep devel` and found the right package for my postgres installation which was 10.

Then simply run `sudo yum install postgresql10-devel`, and eureka!

Comment: You saved my day! Finding the correct devel version really help!

Answer (score 3):

On mac make sure your postgres is linked. 
You can do it by

```
brew link --overwrite postgresql
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

try  this:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
gem install pg
```

it would be works!

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu-16. And I use the method showed here:https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/    to install postgresql-9.6; 
And I use `"sudo apt-get install libpq-dev"` to install the devlib.But It still can't work. So I use the method `ln` to establish soft link, here it is : 
`sudo ln -s /usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h /usr/include/`;
`sudo ln -s /usr/include/postgresql/postgres_ext.h /usr/include/`
And I solve the problem at last.

Answer (score 1):

`brew install postgresql` worked for me.

Installation of postgresql was giving another error

`Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/local/share/info
/usr/local/share/man/man3`

This error was fixed by giving access to the mentioned directories to the current user

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) (path)`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed `postgresql` on MacOS via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install postgresql@95 # 9.5 is the version needed in my project
```

you may need to find the `pg_config` depending on your version of `libpq`

my project needed older version of `pg`.

```
gem install pg -v '0.20.0' -- --with-pg config=/usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.1/bin/pg_config
```