# Package configuration for libxml2 is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml-parsing, windows-10, ruby-on-rails-5

I was in a bundle install after adding in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'pg',  '0.20.0'
gem 'fog', '1.42'
gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'
gem 'rails_stdout_logging'
```

but Bundler cannot continue after an error while installling ovirt-engine-sdk (4.2.3). The log says:

```
find_executable: checking for xml2-config... -------------------- no --------------------
package configuration for libxml2 is not found
```

I'm on windows 10, completely lost with the instructions I've found here https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/tree/master/win32

This library is needed for some reason, but not the 4 gems listed above. Anyhow I need it!

Here is my Gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
      repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
      "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
    end


    gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.5'
    gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
    gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
    gem 'devise', '~> 4.4', '>= 4.4.1'
    gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.1'
    gem 'inherited_resources'
    gem 'active_skin'
    gem 'paperclip', '~> 6.0.0'
    gem 'cancancan'


    group :development, :test do
      # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
      gem 'sqlite3'
      # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
      gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
      gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
      gem 'selenium-webdriver'
    end

    group :development do
      # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
      gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
    end

    group :production do
      gem 'pg',  '0.20.0'
      gem 'fog', '1.42'
      gem 'rails_serve_static_assets' # for Static Assets on Heroku 
      gem 'rails_stdout_logging' # needed with the above one
    end

    # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
    gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same problem on my fresh ubuntu 18.04, installing a rails project.

a similar issue was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728438/rails-broken-bundle-not-working-ovirt-engine-sdk-error-failed-to-build-ge/49733679)

So the fix for me was

`sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`

then I got a similar prob with libcurl and fixed it with

`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

then I had a prob with pg and fixed it

`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`  from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086073/rails-install-pg-cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header)

Answer (score 0):

I've isolated the problem caused by this line in config/application.rb `config.serve_static_assets = true` added together with the gems for heroku in production.