# Rails broken - bundle not working - ovirt-engine-sdk - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. Cloud9 AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, aws-cloud9

I am working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Rails5) by Michael Hartl in the AWS Cloud9 environment. I'm finishing chapter 11 now. (new to programming as well)

It appears I have broken something related to the Rails (or Ruby) system.  I am no longer able to start the Rails server, test or console.

The error message I get usually starts with this, which I have not had any luck finding much information on here or via Google.  ovirt-engine-sdk -v '4.2.3'

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize': Could not find ovirt-engine-sdk-4.2.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Trying `bundle install` or `bundle update` I get outputs like this:

```
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies......
Using rake 12.3.1
Using CFPropertyList 2.3.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.1.4
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.7.1
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Using nokogiri 1.8.2
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.4 (was 1.0.3)
Using loofah 2.2.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
Using actionview 5.1.4
Using rack 2.0.4
Using rack-test 1.0.0
Using actionpack 5.1.4
Using nio4r 2.3.0
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using actioncable 5.1.4
Using globalid 0.4.1
Using activejob 5.1.4
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using mail 2.7.0
Using actionmailer 5.1.4
Using activemodel 5.1.4
Using arel 8.0.0
Using activerecord 5.1.4
Using ansi 1.5.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using autoprefixer-rails 8.2.0
Using bcrypt 3.1.11
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using ffi 1.9.23
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.5.6
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
Using will_paginate 3.1.6
Using bootstrap-will_paginate 1.0.0
Using bundler 1.16.1
Using byebug 9.0.6
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using mime-types 3.1
Using carrierwave 1.2.2
Using coderay 1.1.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using method_source 0.9.0
Using thor 0.20.0
Using railties 5.1.4
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using unf_ext 0.0.7.5
Using unf 0.1.4
Using domain_name 0.5.20170404
Using excon 0.62.0
Using faker 1.7.3
Using fission 0.5.0
Using formatador 0.2.5
Using fog-core 1.45.0
Using multi_json 1.13.1
Using fog-json 1.0.2
Using ipaddress 0.8.3
Using xml-simple 1.1.5
Using fog-aliyun 0.2.0
Using fog-xml 0.1.3
Using fog-atmos 0.1.0
Using fog-aws 2.0.1
Using inflecto 0.0.2
Using fog-brightbox 0.14.0
Using fog-cloudatcost 0.1.2
Using fog-digitalocean 0.3.0
Using fog-dnsimple 1.0.0
Using fog-dynect 0.0.3
Using fog-ecloud 0.3.0
Using fog-google 0.1.0
Using fog-internet-archive 0.0.1
Using fog-joyent 0.0.1
Using fog-local 0.5.0
Using fog-openstack 0.1.25
Using json 2.1.0
Fetching ovirt-engine-sdk 4.2.3
Installing ovirt-engine-sdk 4.2.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.2.3/ext/ovirtsdk4c
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180409-4891-qfsq17.rb extconf.rb
checking for xml2-config... yes
checking for curl-config... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-libcurl-config
        --without-libcurl-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
extconf.rb:40:in `<main>': The "libcurl" package isn't available. (RuntimeError)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.2.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.2.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ovirt-engine-sdk (4.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ovirt-engine-sdk -v '4.2.3'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  fog was resolved to 1.42.0, which depends on
    fog-ovirt was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on
      ovirt-engine-sdk
```

Looking at the `gem_make.out` file results from the above output shows this:

```
current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.2.3/ext/ovirtsdk4c
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180409-4891-qfsq17.rb extconf.rb
checking for xml2-config... yes
checking for curl-config... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-libcurl-config
        --without-libcurl-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
extconf.rb:40:in `<main>': The "libcurl" package isn't available. (RuntimeError)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.2.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

The output of the mkmf.log mentioned above is:

```
find_executable: checking for xml2-config... -------------------- yes

--------------------

find_executable: checking for curl-config... -------------------- no

--------------------

"pkg-config --exists libcurl"
package configuration for libcurl is not found
```

So I'm stuck.. I can't get the `ovirt-engine-sdk-4.23` to install at this point.

Thanks in advance for any help.  Please let me know if there are any other files or information you need to assist.

Comment: So looking at the last error `libcurl` is not found, I googled to find this command to install it: `sudo yum install libcurl libcurl-devel`   I ran that, which resulted in the system downloading and installing libcurl successfully.    Once that was complete I ran `bundle update` which now made it further in the install - to fail at this point 'Installing pg 0.20.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.'    Will read up some more on the error codes produced and post updates.

Comment: Running `sudo yum install postgresql-devel` resolved the pg 0.20.0 issue and I am now able to complete the bundle update and rails seems to be working again.  I had to run `bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to get the server to run again, after that it has been fine.

Comment: Usually, when gems fail to install, it's not Rails that is broken. Its your machine that has lacking dependencies for said gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to fix this by:

1. Installing libcurl developer version:

   `sudo yum install libcurl libcurl-devel`

Once that was complete I ran bundle update which now made it further in the install - to fail at this point `Installing pg 0.20.0 with native extensions Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

2. Running `sudo yum install postgresql-devel` resolved the pg 0.20.0 issue and I am now able to complete the bundle update and rails seems to be working again.
3. Rails server had an issue booting after all of this. This command got it working again: `bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

After that the environment and rails all seems to be working fine again.

Answer (score 27):

For `ubuntu` users:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Edit:

For `fedora` users:(mine is Fedora 32)

```
sudo dnf install libcurl libcurl-devel
```

If libcurl is already there, just:

```
sudo dnf install libcurl-devel
```

Installation can be checked with:

`dnf list installed libcurl` and `dnf list installed libcurl-devel`

Answer (score 15):

You can easy solve this on linux/debian or ubuntu by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

You should be fine.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using an Ubuntu system then use the following command:

> sudo apt-get --assume-yes install gcc libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev ruby ruby-dev

then run

> bundle install

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu, try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

and then run

```
$ bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue:

```
In Gemfile:
  fog was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
    fog-ovirt was resolved to 1.1.6, which depends on
      ovirt-engine-sdk
```

ovirt 4.3.0 threw the following error:

```
Fetching ovirt-engine-sdk 4.3.0
Installing ovirt-engine-sdk 4.3.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.3.0/ext/ovirtsdk4c
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20190508-5580-eyxazz.rb extconf.rb
checking for xml2-config... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

I was then able to bundle install successfully after running:

```
sudo yum install libxml2 libxml2-devel
```

HOWEVER, sudo yum install libxml2 **libxml2-dev** was not successful

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 19.04**(Disco Dingo)
Firstly, locate the **mkmf.log** file and check for what is causing the error(s).
If there is something like this message logged:  *The "libxml2" package isn't available.*
Head over to [**here**](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/disco/+source/libxml2), choose the right version which should take you to a page like [**this**](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.04/ubuntu-main-i386/libxml2-dev_2.9.4+dfsg1-7ubuntu3_i386.deb.html) , for **libxml2-dev** for example, follow the instructions in the **[Install Howto](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.04/ubuntu-main-i386/libxml2-dev_2.9.4+dfsg1-7ubuntu3_i386.deb.html#howto)**. Running `bundle install` afterwards should be a success.