# Gemfile.lock can't be regenerated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am on a new computer (OSX 12.6) with an old app...(rails 5)
I am trying to update all...

Most of my gems are not active anymore and I updating one by one but my Gemfile.lock keep the old... So I tried to remove it but it's impossible to regenerate it...
I did `bundle install` and `bundle update` nothing worked

I searched and found similar problem, someone said, this worked...

```
Bundler.with_clean_env { Dir.chdir("/path/to/myapp") { `bundle install` } }
```

But I've no idea where I should put this ? ( I haven't been doing webdev for 4 years at least....)

receving error like this when I bundle install

```
An error occurred while installing ovirt-engine-sdk (4.4.1), and
Bundler cannot continue.
```

Comment: done but not sure it helps

Comment: Deleting Gemfile.lock on an older application is not a good idea, unless you have very carefully pinned versions in your Gemfile.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728438/rails-broken-bundle-not-working-ovirt-engine-sdk-error-failed-to-build-ge -- looks like you don't have some depedencies installed on your Mac.

Comment: what is the command for Mac user?

Comment: check out Homebrew for installing packages on the Mac https://brew.sh

Comment: I've installed Homebrew already