# Error message: Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a problem with ruby. I tried a lot but nothing works for me.

When i want to start the rails server, i get this error message:

> An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that "gem install pg -v '0.18.1" succeeds before bundling.

This is what i tried already:

```
sudo install gem
bundle install
bundle install --path vendor/cache
gem install pg -v '0.18.1'
```

When i try `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'`i get this error message:

> Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or installed on this machine.
>   Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

But `bundle install`doesn't work either. I get this error message:

> An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'` succeeds before bundling.

I also tried to start the server in a new ruby project.

Nothing helps..

Thanks for your help!

These are my changes in my Gemfile:

```
group :production do
   gem 'pg'
   gem 'rails_12factor'
 end

group :development do
   gem 'sqlite3'
 end
```

Comment: Add complete console log

Comment: What's your operating system? Have you installed client package and its dev package of postgresql before you install gem pg? Did you install them via package manager(like apt or yum) or just downloaded the binary version and decompressed it?

Comment: i downloaded a dev package for os x. my console log is: `$ rails server
Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run gem pristine --all for better startup performance.
Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or installed on this machine.
Run bundle install to install missing gems.`

Comment: Iam pretty sure you did not install postgres

Comment: I really don't know why, it worked a week...

Comment: can you post your gemfile code as well?

Comment: This question, unable to install pg gem, has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq - the accepted solution is to set ARCHFLAGS: `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My teacher at Bloc had the solution! If anybody have the same problem run the following commands:

1. `spring stop`
2. `gem uninstall pg`
3. `bundle install --without production`

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 144):

If you're on **Ubuntu**, most likely you're missing a hidden dependency

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

If you are on **OS X**, try these steps

- Install Xcode command line tools (Apple Developer site). If you have
  it already installed, update it using `brew update`.
- `brew uninstall postgresql`
- `brew install postgresql`
- `gem install pg`

Comment: i did this, it works well, but when i try to start the server i get again: `Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run gem pristine --all for better startup performance.
Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or installed on this machine.`

Comment: Make sure you're installing the pg gem in the ruby package used by your project.

Comment: Worked for me on El Capitan. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and this tip worked for me. Thank you

Comment: It took me forever to find this answer but it certainly worked (unlike all of the other solutions I tried). THANK YOU!

Answer (score 30):

If you are an Ubuntu user you need to do the following prior installing the gem

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Then perform `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'` or just `bundle install` if you have you r gem in a GEMFILE.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using Mac and Homebrew, Looks like libpqxx lib was missing.

```
brew install libpqxx
```

This command should do it.

Answer (score 16):

If you are not sure where your pg_config is, and assuming you are on Linux or Mac, you can run the following command:

```
which pg_config
```

this will return ==>   `/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config`

now use this path as

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
```

Done now `bundle install`

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! I had run the `gem install` command with the flags for pg_config but when I ran `bundle install`, bundler was using a different version of pg_config. This solved it!

Answer (score 4):

`ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install` worked for me as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629953/bundle-failing-cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq).

Comment: This question, unable to install the pg gem, is already answered here, and setting ARCHFLAGS is the accepted solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq

Answer (score 1):

Bundler has some problem identifing the PostgreSQL server path. If you are pretty sure that the your PostgreSQL server is installed properly, all you need to do should be adding the path to this to `PATH` variable. Example command:

```
export PATH=/path/to/postgres/bin/:$PATH
```

If you would still have some issues, it is very likely that you have something wrong with PostgreSQL install. If so, try installing [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) and execute command as below:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/:$PATH
```

Make sure that the version is correct.

Comment: This also doesn't work. i get again this error: `Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run gem pristine --all for better startup performance.
Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or installed on this machine.
Run bundle install to install missing gems.
Patricks-MacBook-Pro:first-app-new patrickhofer$`

Comment: And what is the result of `bundle install`? Is it finishing with success?

Comment: No `bundle install` does not work. This error: `An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install pg -v '0.18.1' succeeds before bundling.`

Comment: Hard to know. After exporting to path have you closed and open new session in terminal?

Comment: do you even have pg in your gemfile?

Comment: @JakubNiechciał No i don't... i try it now.

Comment: can try to add a version to your gem pg? and run bundle update?

Comment: Additionally, if you have installed postgres via `brew install`, try to uninstall it, uninstall Postgres.app and than install Postgres.app again. After successful install of Postgres.app, run the export PATH that I mentioned (`export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/:$PATH`), close the terminal, open terminal again and run `bundle install`.

Comment: `.bash_profile` can e.g. export additional directories to your PATH. First of all, you should add there a path to your local bins: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

Anyone running in to this (a year later!) using Rails 5.1.2 I did the following after first installing and initiating Postgresql (Centos 7).
So assuming you've already got postgresql installed and the postgres server&user set up.(+ the usual standard dev tools for Linux).

```
Add extra deps for rails to build gems.

$ sudo yum install postgresql-devel

Add postgres path in ~/.profile   

export PATH=/usr/bin/postgres:$PATH  (or your installed path)

Add another user/role with create db privileges using pgAdmin or shell
(should be the same user as the system/rails user because the postgres user doesn't have permissions for /rails/db/schema.rb, but the system/rails user does)

Below are shell commands for postgres create role and database.

$ sudo -u postgres psql (enter postgres password)
$ create role (linux/rails user) with createdb login password 'password';
$ \du  (check its done and has createDB privs)
$ CREATE DATABASE name;
```

You will automatically become owner of the new database if no other arguments are presented.

Or you can use a gui like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/) to do the same.

```
So the above sets up for rails to access postgresql and build the pg gem once you've swapped out the default Gemfile & config/database.yml

Now create app and set it up (no need for -d postgresql flag because we swap out the Gemfile and the config/database.yml file contents completely and rails will install a postgresql db on bundle update/install.

(change some to rake for earlier versions of rails)

$ rails new app
$ cd app
$ atom (or editor) Gemfile config/database.yml
Swap out both file contents (to ones shown below) & save.
$ bundle update
$ bundle install

Check it with

$ rails db:create

(postgresql database should now be connected), so scaffold something

$ rails g scaffold Users name:string email:string comment:text
$ rails db:migrate
$ rails server

http://localhost:3000 shows the default page and http://localhost:3000/users brings up your new Users page using postgresql not sqlite3. Put something in to test it.
```

Below are the Gemfile and config/database.yml files I used for Rails 5.1.2, including taps for Heroku.

Gemfile rails 5.1.2

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails',        '5.1.2'
    gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
    gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
    gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
    gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
    gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
    gem 'jbuilder',     '2.7.0'
    gem 'taps'

    #Postgresql Database
    group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.21.0'
    end

    group :development, :test do
      gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
      gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri
    end

    group :development do
      gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
      gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
      gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
      gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
    end
    # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
    gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

config/database.yml file contents (watch out for indentation)

development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: development or app_name
    pool: 5
    username: (user created for postgres/rails)
    password: password
    host: localhost


test:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: development or app_name
    pool: 5
    username: (user created for postgres/rails)
    password: password
    host: localhost


production:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: development or app_name
    pool: 5
    username: (user created for postgres/rails)
    password: password
    host: localhost
```

Doing all the above will get you a dev/prod postgresql database in rails but no test, you can also access the database directly from rails by just running "rails db" and entering password.

Its simple but gets you up and running with rails/postgresql quickly.

Answer (score 1):

For Alpine linux, you'd want to install `postgresql-dev` first:

```
apk add --update postgresql-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install `pg` like this:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir=/path/to/postgresql/root
```

If it doesn't work, try

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/path/to/postgresql/root/include \
                  --with-pg-lib=/path/to/postgresql/root/lib
```

Comment: Whit this i get: `ERROR:  Error installing pg:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

Answer (score 0):

**PostgreSQL setup on CentOS 6**

```
[root@git2 ~]# yum install postgresql-server
[root@git2 ~]# psql 
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
[root@git2 ~]# /etc/init.d/postgresql 
Usage: /etc/init.d/postgresql {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload|initdb}
[root@git2 ~]# /etc/init.d/postgresql start

/var/lib/pgsql/data is missing. Use "service postgresql initdb" to initialize the cluster first.
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@git2 ~]# service postgresql initdb
Initializing database:                                     [  OK  ]
[root@git2 ~]# 
[root@git2 ~]# /etc/init.d/postgresql start
Starting postgresql service:                               [  OK  ]
[root@git2 ~]# psql 
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "root"
[root@git2 ~]# 
[root@git2 ~]# su - postgres
-bash-4.1$ psql
psql (8.4.13)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collation  |    Ctype    |   Access privilege
s   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
----
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres
                                                             : postgres=CTc/postg
res
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres
                                                             : postgres=CTc/postg
res
(3 rows)

postgres=# 
postgres=# \q
-bash-4.1$ 
-bash-4.1$ pwd
/var/lib/pgsql
-bash-4.1$ wget -q http://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/booktown.sql
-bash-4.1$ ls -lh booktown.sql 
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres 42K Jan 11  2005 booktown.sql
-bash-4.1$ psql -f booktown.sql 
CREATE DATABASE
(snip)
-bash-4.1$ psql
psql (8.4.13)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collation  |    Ctype    |   Access privilege
s   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
----
 booktown  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres
                                                             : postgres=CTc/postg
res
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres
                                                             : postgres=CTc/postg
res
(4 rows)

postgres=# 
postgres=# \q
-bash-4.1$ 
-bash-4.1$ pg_dumpall > /tmp/pg_dumpall.`date +%s`.sql
-bash-4.1$ ls -lh /tmp/pg_dumpall.1349195444.sql 
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres 44K Oct  2 12:30 /tmp/pg_dumpall.1349195444.sql
-bash-4.1$ 
-bash-4.1$ pg_dump --clean booktown > /tmp/pg_dump-booktown.`date +%s`.sql 
-bash-4.1$ ls -lh /tmp/pg_dump-booktown.1349196164.sql 
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres 46K Oct  2 12:42 /tmp/pg_dump-booktown.1349196164.sql
-bash-4.1$ 
-bash-4.1$ psql booktown
psql (8.4.13)
Type "help" for help.

booktown=# 
booktown=# \d
(snip)
 public | subjects              | table    | postgres
 public | text_sorting          | table    | postgres

booktown=# SELECT * FROM subjects;
  0 | Arts             | Creativity St
  1 | Business         | Productivity Ave
(snip)
```

**PostgreSQL setup on Fedora 20**

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install postgresql-server
(snip)
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start postgresql.service
Job for postgresql.service failed. See 'systemctl status postgresql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status postgresql.service
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2014-01-18 08:08:38 EST; 12s ago
  Process: 4921 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 18 08:08:38 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
Jan 18 08:08:38 localhost.localdomain postgresql-check-db-dir[4921]: "/var/lib/pgsql/data" is missing or empty.
Jan 18 08:08:38 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 18 08:08:38 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
Jan 18 08:08:38 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]# postgresql-setup initdb
Initializing database ... OK
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start postgresql.service
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl stop postgresql.service
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]# cp -a /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf.orig
[root@localhost ~]# # insecure... just for dev...
[root@localhost ~]# vim /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
[root@localhost ~]# diff /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf.orig /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
80c80
< local   all             all                                     peer
---
> local   all             all                                     trust
82c82
< host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
---
> host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start postgresql.service
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]# su - postgres
-bash-4.2$ psql -c '\du'
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}

-bash-4.2$ psql -c "CREATE ROLE pguser1 UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'secret1' NOSUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE NOINHERIT LOGIN"
CREATE ROLE
-bash-4.2$ psql -c '\du'
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 pguser1   | No inheritance, Create role, Create DB         | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}

-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ psql -c '\l'
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)

-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ psql -c "CREATE DATABASE pgdatabase1 WITH OWNER = pguser1"
CREATE DATABASE
-bash-4.2$ psql -c '\l'
                                   List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 pgdatabase1 | pguser1  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
             |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
             |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

-bash-4.2$
```