# Can't install pg (0.18.4) OR mime-types-data (3.2016.0221)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to set up a ruby on rails project with a postgresql database and this is happening:

When I add gem 'pg' to the gemfile and run `bundle install` this is the output:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` this happens:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen
```

When I run `sudo gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.18.4
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for pg-0.18.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for pg-0.18.4...
```

When I run `sudo bundle install` :

```
An error occurred while installing mime-types-data (3.2016.0221), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mime-types-data -v '3.2016.0221'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run `sudo gem install mime-types-data -v '3.2016.0221'`

```
ERROR:  Error installing mime-types-data:
        mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
```

When I run `ruby -v` :

```
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
```

When I run `sudo ruby -v` :

```
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux
```

I'm using rbenv. There are several posts about the problems I have, and I tried several things, but nothing seems to work me. Here is what I have already tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev (I use Ubuntu)
```

a possible solution from: [Error message: Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'` succeeds before bundling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162572/error-message-make-sure-that-gem-install-pg-v-0-18-1-succeeds-before-bundl)

```
which pg_config

this will return ==> /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config

now use this path as

bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config

Done now bundle install
```

didn't work. At this point, I'm lost. I have another ruby on rails project, which runs without problems, but every new project I start, has this problem. Any advices?

Comment: try this  sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-server-dev-9.3

Comment: I did it and then I ran sudo bundle install and this came: An error occurred while installing byebug (9.0.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '9.0.4'` succeeds before bundling. When i do gem install byebug -v '9.0.4', this comes: ERROR:  Error installing byebug:
        byebug requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.

Comment: Please go through this link https://github.com/YaleSTC/shifts/issues/258

Comment: I changed the gem byebug to gem 'pry-byebug', platform: [:ruby_20] and when I run sudo bundle install, it seems to work, but whenever I use bundle install, as I usually do, the same error with pg 0.18.4 comes. Do I need now to make sudo before everything I do?

Comment: Actually, when I use sudo bundle install, the error with pg 0.18.4 happens.

Comment: You don't need to do sudo bundle install.

Comment: If I use bundle install, this happens: An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Now, the only thing you can do is uninstall PG from the system and just follow this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-04 . It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted Ruby and I re-installed Ruby and it seems to work now.