# an error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby on rails and installing bundle after all required configurations like **rvm,ruby,rails** etc. But Error on bundle install

```
an error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and bundler cannot continue.
```

with this another problem after this Please suggest me how to update my old rails application to latest rails.

Please is there any suggestion ???

Comment: You're missing a hidden dependency

Comment: should I install this through terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: Make sure that \`gem install pg -v '0.18.1'\` succeeds before bundling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162572/error-message-make-sure-that-gem-install-pg-v-0-18-1-succeeds-before-bundl)

Comment: Thanks @ArunKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install missing a hidden dependency by running this command into your terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

You can update your old project of rails to the latest one go through the steps mention on this link

http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2015/12/upgrading-to-ruby-on-rails-5-0-from-rails-4-2-application-use-case/

Comment: Thanks @Priyadarshani mini

Answer (score 1):

If you're on **Ubuntu**, most likely you're missing a hidden dependency

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```