# libpq native extension crashed on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, libpq

i'm trying to install pg ( postgreSQL gem ) on my Mac and got this error

```
  Installing pg 0.18.1 with native extensions

  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

  current directory: /private/var/folders/h5/slvxw4xd0d30dxzxf8vg5c600000gp/T/bundler20160302-7420-1orffo8pg-0.18.1/gems/pg-0.18.1/ext
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160302-7420-h4zq8h.rb extconf.rb
  checking for pg_config... yes
  Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
    checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
    checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
    checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
    checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
    checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
    checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
    Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
  *** extconf.rb failed ***
  Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
  libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
  need configuration options.

  Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib

  To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

    /var/folders/h5/slvxw4xd0d30dxzxf8vg5c600000gp/T/bundler20160302-7420-1orffo8pg-0.18.1/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/pg-0.18.1/mkmf.log

  extconf failed, exit code 1

  Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/h5/slvxw4xd0d30dxzxf8vg5c600000gp/T/bundler20160302-7420-1orffo8pg-0.18.1/gems/pg-0.18.1 for inspection.
  Results logged to /var/folders/h5/slvxw4xd0d30dxzxf8vg5c600000gp/T/bundler20160302-7420-1orffo8pg-0.18.1/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/pg-0.18.1/gem_make.out
```

So i check all my packages installed :

Mac OS X El Capitan v10.11.3

```
$ruby -v
-> ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
$rails -v    
-> Rails 4.2.5.1
$brew -v
-> Homebrew 0.9.5 (git revision c9aee; last commit 2016-02-15)
$benv -v
-> rbenv 0.4.0
$postgres -V    
-> postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.5
$xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
$gcc --version
-> Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
    Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
    Thread model: posix
```

I don't want to have installed postgre via browser app download, i want it via brew package, so there is a way to install the annoying libpq ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need libpq for postgres to work with ruby on Mac OSX.

If you installed postgres with `Postgres.app`, you sould be able to remove it by simply moving `postgres.app` to the trash can and deleting the data directory from `~/Library/Application Support/Postgres` (only if you want to delete all existing postgres databases on your machine)

Then, with homebrew, install postgres via `brew install postgresql`. The `pg` gem should work directly with the postgres Homebrew install.

Comment: My laptop is purely new, there are any databases, and i haven't installed postgre via app, i did it via bre install postgresql and  when i try to start a new rails project... booom !! crashed everything because of the libpq :S