# pg gem install fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Centos 6.9
(similar to question: [Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq) but that one is on MacOS not Centos, so those solutions did not work

ruby 2.1.8 (tried 2.2)

rails 4.2.6 (tried 5.0)

postgres 9.3

I am trying to install the pg gem with:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pqlib=/usr/lib64/libpqxx-4.0.so --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config
```

I keep trying to feed it different libraries but the one it is getting stuck on is some `PQconnectdb()` function. Error below

Rails used to be installed on this computer with pg but something happend after an update.. Any ideas here?

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext
/home/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170425-12873-191077o.rb extconf.rb --with-pqlib=/usr/lib64/libpqxx-4.0.so --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config
extconf.rb:34: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt/anaconda in PATH, mode 040777
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -l/usr/lib64/libpqxx-4.0.so... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Installed pg libraries:`Installed Packages
postgresql93.x86_64                                   9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-contrib.x86_64                           9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-debuginfo.x86_64                         9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-devel.x86_64                             9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-docs.x86_64                              9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-libs.x86_64                              9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-odbc.x86_64                              09.06.0100-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-odbc-debuginfo.x86_64                    09.03.0400-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-plperl.x86_64                            9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-plpython.x86_64                          9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-pltcl.x86_64                             9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-server.x86_64                            9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6

postgresql93-tcl.x86_64                               2.1.1-1.rhel6

postgresql93-tcl-debuginfo.x86_64                     2.1.1-1.rhel6

postgresql93-test.x86_64                              9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6`

Comment: postgresql libs installed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq similar issues here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq)

Comment: The possible duplicate is on MacOS, this is on Centos.. different dependency issues

Comment: updated with postgresql libs installed

Comment: There are also answers for linux on that answer of the other question, it is for sure the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried this?

    $ sudo su
    $ env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a linux brew package manager, which had some old dependencies that messed with the pg gem install.

The answer is:

- Remove [linux brew][1]

  [1]: http://linuxbrew.sh/
- Uninstall Ruby With RVM
- Implode RVM
- Reinstall RVM
- Reinstall ruby
- Install pg gem with a pg config option:

`gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$ sudo su
$ env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

Comment: Yeah, that one throw a `checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***` error, even if I use: `--with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config`