# Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq) when install gem pg -v '1.2.3'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
gem install pg -v '1.2.3'

checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/aleksejmelehov/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pq-dir
    --without-pq-dir
    --with-pq-include
    --without-pq-include=${pq-dir}/include
    --with-pq-lib
    --without-pq-lib=${pq-dir}/lib
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpq-dir
    --without-libpq-dir
    --with-libpq-include
    --without-libpq-include=${libpq-dir}/include
    --with-libpq-lib
    --without-libpq-lib=${libpq-dir}/lib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpq-dir
    --without-ms/libpq-dir
    --with-ms/libpq-include
    --without-ms/libpq-include=${ms/libpq-dir}/include
    --with-ms/libpq-lib
    --without-ms/libpq-lib=${ms/libpq-dir}/lib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib`

sudo gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-pg-config=/Users/aleksejmelehov/.asdf/installs/postgres/15.3/bin/pg_config -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=/Users/aleksejmelehov/.asdf/installs/postgres/15.3/bin/pg_config -- --with-cflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration
```

Comment: You'll need to install `libpq` first. The method to do this depends entirely on your operating system. In this case, can you [use Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libpq)?

Comment: After installation, the error persisted.

Comment: The next step is you might need to specify the path if it's not in a standard location. That's what all those options are for.

Comment: This issue is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq