# RoR application deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running "heroku run rake db:migrate" after I have deployed my app to heroku and I get this:

$>>heroku run rake db:migrate

```
Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I try installing the gem mentioned but nothing happens. I am using rails3 an ruby 1.9.3, and my database.yml file contains:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

How can I fix this error?

EDIT:

running
$>>sudo gem install pg -v '0.13.2'

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.13.2/ext/gem_make.out
```

I am getting this error. Again I am using 1.9.3 version of ruby.

Comment: Are you trying to use postgresql or sqlite3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database.yml is setup to use sqlite3.

If you want to use postgresql you need to install postgres on your computer first.

For Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

For Max OS X:

```
brew install postgresql
```

Make you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed first.

heroku autogenerates database.yml on the deploy. Reads like: it doesn't matter what you put in your database.yml, which to me is nice, as I can include it in git without worrying about production db passwords.

Then install the pg gem by putting this in your Gemfile:

gem 'pg', :require => 'pg'

if you are using an older version of Rails use the gem install method.

Comment: Eric, Heroku always uses Postgres, no matter what you put in `database.yml`. But unless you are rolling your own SQL, there is no harm in running SQLite locally and Postgres on Heroku. The OP's original problem was related to Heroku deployment; now he is running into another problem installing Postgres locally, which is different from what the original question was about.

Comment: Hey I found a working solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/unable-to-install-pg-gem-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 'pg' gem to your Gemfile (and then `bundle install`).

Comment: how do I configure it to use postgersql?

Comment: @EricSites, Heroku always uses Postgres, no matter what you put in `database.yml`.

Comment: @TestTest, if you just want to get your app working as quickly as possible, you can always `bundle install` *on a machine which has a working install of Postgres*. It's better to have it running on your development machine too, but that is a different problem from what you originally asked for help with. OR, you can hack `Gemfile.lock` by hand -- I've done this before when developing on Windows and deploying to Heroku, because some gems I needed to use couldn't be installed on Windows.