# Error message when trying to run the command: bundle install --without production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, command-line

When I try to run the

```
bundle install --without production
```

command on Ubuntu 12.04, I get an error message like this:

```
Could not find gem 'pg0.12.2 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine
```

Any ideas about why this is happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 0.12.2 gem to be installed please write in the following way.

```
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
```

If you want version which is greater than 0.12.2 then write in following way

```
gem 'pg' , '>= 0.12.2'
```

Please use this link to know more about how to bundle gems in rails [Bundle](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html)

Comment: When I typed:
`gem install 'pg', '0.12.2'`
it is saying: 
`Could not find a valid gem '0.12.2' (>= 0) in any repository`

Comment: Could you please post your complete bundle file here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/unable-to-install-pg-gem-on-ubuntu Hope this helps

Comment: You dont need to have gem install 'pg' , '0.12.2'. Just doing gem install 'pg' will install the gem with the lastest version i.e. 0.14.0. If you want to install version 0.12.2 then please use -v options while installing `gem install pg -v 0.12.2`

Comment: still getting the `Could not find gem 'pg0.12.2 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.` error

Comment: Just follow the steps 1) Open terminal 2) Just write `gem install pg -v 0.12.2` 3) If still getting error then please paste it here

Comment: here is my gemfile:

`source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.7'

group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3', '3.2.8' 
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :product do
 gem 'pg' '0.14.0'
end`

Comment: Please add , between gem 'pg' and '0.14.0 it should be `gem 'pg' , '0.14.0'`