# How to install "pg" gem for rails 3 on ubuntu "can not build native extensions"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to install pg gem on ubuntu - Can’t find the 'libpq-fe.h header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/unable-to-install-pg-gem-on-ubuntu-cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header)

Whenever I try to install the pg gem for my Rails project, it gives me `Error "failed to build native extensions"`.

I already used a couple of tricks but failed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev build-essential
```

or:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-client libpq5 libpq-dev
```

then:

```
$ sudo gem install pg
```

Comment: You also need to add `libpq-dev` to that list, then it should work to install the gem as asked.

Answer (score 1):

This is a traditional problem if you are installing the pg gem for Rails and getting this error.

Run the following commands on your terminal:

1. `mv ~/.rvm/usr/lib ~/.rvm/usr/lib_rvm`
2. `gem install pg -v '0.14.1'`
3. `mv ~/.rvm/usr/lib_rvm ~/.rvm/usr/lib`

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Gemfile and add `gem pg` to the file. It will make sense to also comment out the `gem sqlite3` instead.

Save the file and then issue the `bundle install` command.

Comment: SQLite3 is not a replacement for PostgreSQL. [See here](http://www.postgresql.org/about/)

Comment: @pwned: thanks for the comment. You are right, if we compare the capabilities of both then PostgreSQL wins http://database-management-systems.findthebest.com/compare/43-53/PostgreSQL-vs-SQLite. I thought the user might want to use only one DBMS for data storage.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. It will work..

sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4

sudo apt-get install pgadmin3