# Errors of pushing rails app to Heroku error occurred while installing sqlite3, and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, sqlite

I was trying to push my rails app to heroku and received errors as below:

-

```
 Counting objects: 177, done. Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (161/161), done. Writing objects: 100%
   (177/177), 44.73 KiB, done. Total 177 (delta 39), reused 0 (delta 0)

   -----> Heroku receiving push
   -----> Ruby/Rails app detected
   -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.1
          Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
   -binstubs bin/
          Fetching gem metadata from 
          Fetching gem metadata from 
          Installing rake (10.0.2)
          Installing i18n (0.6.1)
          Installing multi_json (1.3.7)
          Installing activesupport (3.2.8)
          Installing builder (3.0.4)
          Installing activemodel (3.2.8)
          Installing erubis (2.7.0)
          Installing journey (1.0.4)
          Installing rack (1.4.1)
          Installing rack-cache (1.2)
          Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
          Installing hike (1.2.1)
          Installing tilt (1.3.3)
          Installing sprockets (2.1.3)
          Installing actionpack (3.2.8)
          Installing mime-types (1.19)
          Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
          Installing treetop (1.4.12)
          Installing mail (2.4.4)
          Installing actionmailer (3.2.8)
          Installing arel (3.0.2)
          Installing tzinfo (0.3.35)
          Installing activerecord (3.2.8)
          Installing activeresource (3.2.8)
          Using bundler (1.2.1)
          Installing coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
          Installing execjs (1.4.0)
          Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
          Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
          Installing json (1.7.5) with native extensions
          Installing rdoc (3.12)
          Installing thor (0.16.0)
          Installing railties (3.2.8)
          Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
          Installing jquery-rails (2.1.3)
          Installing rails (3.2.8)
          Installing sass (3.2.3)
          Installing sass-rails (3.2.5)
          Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions
          Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native ex tension.
          /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
          checking for sqlite3.h... no
          sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
          or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path ( the
          location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
          *** extconf.rb failed ***
          Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
          necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
          details.  You may need configuration options.
          Provided configuration options:
          --with-opt-dir
          --without-opt-dir
          --with-opt-include
          --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
          --with-opt-lib
          --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
          --with-make-prog
          --without-make-prog
          --srcdir=.
          --curdir
          --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
          --with-sqlite3-dir
          --without-sqlite3-dir
          --with-sqlite3-include
          --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
          --with-sqlite3-lib
          --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
          --enable-local
          --disable-local
          Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2pense1pvyqut/vendor/bundle /ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6
   for inspection.
          Results logged to /tmp/build_2pense1pvyqut/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
   sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
          An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot co ntinue.
          Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.

    !  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.  !  !     Heroku push
   rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

=========================================

My GemFile as below:

=======================================

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

   # Bundle edge Rails instead:
   # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git' 

   group :production do    gem 'pg' end

   group :development, :test do   gem 'taps'   gem 'rvm'
        gem 'rspec-rails','2.0.1'   gem 'annotate'   gem 'faker','0.3.1'   gem 'rspec','2.0.1'   gem 'webrat','0.7.1'   gem 'spork','0.8.4'  
   gem 'factory_girl_rails','1.0' end

   gem 'rake', '~> 10.0.1'



   #gem 'yaml_db'

   # Gems used only for assets and not required
   # in production environments by default.   group :assets do   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

     # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more
   supported runtimes   # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

     gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3' end

   gem 'jquery-rails'

   # To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
   # gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

   # To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
   # gem 'jbuilder'

   # Use unicorn as the app server
   # gem 'unicorn'

   # Deploy with Capistrano
   # gem 'capistrano'

   # To use debugger
   # gem 'debugger'
```

=======================================

I tried almost all the solutions provided online, but still no luck.
   Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 23):

I don't see it in your code above, but guessing you probably have your `gem 'sqlite3'` at the top of your gemfile, so it is being used in all environments. Sqlite is not supported on Heroku so it has be kept out of the production group. Try the following so that you can use **sqlite** for development and testing and then **pg** on Heroku.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

---

Comment: Thank u Memoht. I finally figured out that is because I was on the branch and I was trying to push master. I switched to master and pushed again, bingo, it worked. Thanks again..

Comment: I was having a similar problem. And I had not committed my removal of sqlite3. O_o stupid mistake, documenting for other people reading this post.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue. Realized that I hadn't committed my changes to Git. Once I committed it and re-pushed it to Heroku, it worked without issue.

Comment: Same here, was trying to push something not yet committed in Git to Heroku. Commit >> push

Comment: Same here, after I changed the gemfile, this error still showed up, telling me installing sqlite failed. I then realized that I only changed the local gemfile. After commit the modified gemfile, then the heroku server does not try to install sqlite again

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me on my Mac:

`group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end`

And then

`bundle install`

but that threw up this error:

`can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header *** extconf.rb failed ***`

Solved this error using Homebrew as explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20482221/2665896

i.e.

```
brew install postgresql
gem install pg
```

Then commit the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to the local master.

Then `git push heroku master` worked like a charm.