# An error occurred while installing pg (0.19.0), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Yesterday I install Ubuntu 16.04.1.

ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

rails -v '4.2.6'
create a rails project

run `bundle` and have an error:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/zeus/.rbenv/versions /2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/.gemtest
An error occurred while installing pg (0.19.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.19.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When run `gem install pg -v '0.19.0'`

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/zeus/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/.gemtest
```

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14102759/155826

Comment: @mysmallidea My eng is bad) I tried to run it but i use rbend

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Ubuntu, You need to install `libpq-dev` package.
Try this one:

`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

For CentOS 7, You need install `postgresql-devel` package.

`sudo yum install postgresql-devel`

Comment: Thank you this fixed the issue for me :)

Comment: This fixed the issue for me even on Ubuntu 16.04 and rails 2.4.0

Comment: libpq-dev is already the newest version (9.5.12-0ubuntu0.16.04).

Answer (score -2):

It is a permission issue. Try

```
sudo chown -R zeus ~/.rbenv
```

Here *zeus* is your username.