# An error occurred while installing pg (0.12.2), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler, railstutorial.org

I'm following the [Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top) & there is a part where he is he he instructs you to update your Gemfile to include:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

And then enter the below commands in your terminal:

```
bundle update
bundle install --without production
```

When you run the bundle update command it throws back the below errors.

```
sample_app:$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using i18n (0.6.4) 
etc
[omitted lines for brevity]
etc
Using railties (3.2.12) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Installing diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.2) 
Installing pg (0.12.2) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    etc
    [omitted lines for brevity]
    etc       



Gem files will remain installed in /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.12.2/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.12.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.12.2'` succeeds before bundling.
sample_app:$
```

I was able to overcome this error easily be removing the `'pg', '0.12.2'` gem from the **Gemfile** & replacing it after running the `bundle update` command.   This seems to work fine as the `'pg', '0.12.2'` gem is aslo omitted in the `without production` flag in the latter `bundle install --without production`.

The `'pg', '0.12.2'` gem is only needed for deploying to heroku with the correct database & everything works fine even when I deployed it to heroku but I'm just wondering if this is  an error in the Tutorial or am I missing something bigger here?

It's also annoying to have to remove this **Gem** everytime I run `bundle update`, is `bundle update` really that necessary?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm following the same tutorial and I think it's redundant to run `update` without modifying **existing** dependency, but in this case it's even causing problems because `update` command has not `--without` argument.

I stumbled upon [Rails 3 cheatsheet](http://envylabs.com/uploads/Rails_3_Cheat_Sheets.pdf) which mentions bundler workflow this way:

> #### After adding or removing dependencies from Gemfile
>
> 1. `$ bundle`
> 2. Commit Gemfile and Gemfile.lock
>
> #### After modifying existing dependency versions
>
> 1. `$ bundle update`
> 2. Commit Gemfile and Gemfile.lock

[image: rails3 cheatsheet: bundler workflow]

---

I read [man pages](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/man/bundle-update.1.html) for `bundle update` and tried **[RECOMMENDED WORKFLOW](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/man/bundle-update.1.html#RECOMMENDED-WORKFLOW)** which consists of running `bundle update` after `bundle install`.

In my case (some output omitted):

```
$ bundle install --without production
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.0.3)
...
Installing rspec-core (2.11.1)
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group production were not installed.             <-- check  


$ bundle update
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.0.3) 
...
Using uglifier (1.2.3) 
Your bundle is updated!
Gems in the group production were not installed.             <-- check
```

I tried it with new RVM gem set and everything was installed correctly.

After that `Gemfile.lock` contains `pg (0.12.2)` and deploying to Heroku works.

> #### RECOMMENDED WORKFLOW
>
> > In general, when working with an application managed with bundler, you
> >     should use the following workflow:
> >
> > After you create your Gemfile for the first time, run
> >
> > `$ bundle install`
> >
> > Check the resulting Gemfile.lock into version control
> >
> > `$ git add Gemfile.lock`
> >
> > When checking out this repository on another development machine, run
> >
> > `$ bundle install`
> >
> > When checking out this repository on a deployment machine, run
> >
> > `$ bundle install --deployment`
> >
> > After changing the Gemfile to reflect a new or update dependency,
> >     run
> >
> > `$ bundle install`
> >
> > Make sure to check the updated Gemfile.lock into version control
> >
> > `$ git add Gemfile.lock`
> >
> > If bundle install reports a conflict, manually update the specific
> >     gems that you changed in the Gemfile
> >
> > `$ bundle update rails thin`
> >
> > If you want to update all the gems to the latest possible versions
> >     that still match the gems listed in the Gemfile, run
> >
> > `$ bundle update`

Comment: If you're following Hartl's GemFile exactly, running `bundle install --without production` initially will fail because of a lock. But then `bundle update` will succeed because it remembers the `--without production`.

Answer (score 1):

Installation of postgres fails with this error : "Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header"

Looks like a lot of people faced this problem, good news is : stackoverflow has the answer ;)

[Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/unable-to-install-pg-gem-on-ubuntu-cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header)

(or at least it should help you to look in the right direction)