# Rails - Issue when running bundle install - Installing pg (0.17.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-postgresql, pg

When running 'bundle install' I get the following error message.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I've tried installing http://postgresapp.com/

but I am still getting the issue? Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass a couple of options on the command line. like this

`gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config`

If you installed postgres to a different location then you'll need to fix up the path to the pg_config file.