# gem install pg not working while doing bundle install / RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

**edit**

What worked for me was running:

```
brew doctor
```

I then had to chown a few files and delete a few things it asked me to.

I then ran

```
sudo gem install pg
```

and it worked. Not sure why it only worked with 'sudo' but when I tried before without it failed

I've used bundler to install a bunch of gems(most failed and I spent hours looking through internet posts on how to install the specific gems.

At the current moment running

```
bundle install
```

complains about the following

```
jacks-MacBook-Pro:techendo jsw$ bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 0.3.39
Using activesupport 4.0.3
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.0.3
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.0.3
Using active_utils 2.2.1
Using json 1.8.1
Using active_shipping 0.12.2
Using activemodel 4.0.3
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Using arel 4.0.2
Using activerecord 4.0.3
Using addressable 2.3.6
Using mini_portile 0.6.0
Using nokogiri 1.6.2.1
Using ruby-hmac 0.4.0
Using amazon-ecs 2.2.5
Using aws-sdk 1.42.0
Using bcrypt 3.1.7
Using multi_xml 0.5.5
Using httparty 0.13.1
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using faraday 0.9.0
Using jwt 1.0.0
Using oauth2 0.9.4
Using bitly 0.10.1
Using sass 3.2.19
Using bootstrap-sass 3.1.1.1
Using buftok 0.2.0
Using cinch 2.1.0
Using climate_control 0.0.3
Using cocaine 0.5.4
Using daemons 1.1.9
Using dalli 2.7.2
Using delayed_job 4.0.1
Using delayed_job_active_record 4.0.1

Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.0.3
Using warden 1.2.3
Using devise 3.2.4
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using equalizer 0.0.9
Using exception_notification 4.0.1
Using excon 0.34.0
Using execjs 2.1.0
Using friendly_id 5.0.4
Using geocoder 1.2.1
Using gibbon 1.1.3
Using google_custom_search 0.3.1
Using heroku-api 0.3.18
Using heroku-deflater 0.5.3
Using hike 1.2.3
Using htmlentities 4.3.2
Using http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Using http 0.6.1
Using imgkit 1.4.1
Using jquery-rails 3.1.0
Using jquery-ui-rails 4.2.1
Using kgio 2.9.2
Using libv8 3.16.14.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using mail_view 2.0.4
Using mandrill-api 1.0.51
Using memcachier 0.0.2
Using memoizable 0.4.2
Using meta-tags 2.0.0
Using mixpanel-ruby 1.4.0
Using naught 1.0.0
Using nested_form 0.3.2
Using newrelic_rpm 3.8.1.221
Using paperclip 4.1.1

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/jsw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
sh: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
sh: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jsw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jsw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jsw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and
Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds
before bundling.
```

On another stack overflow post the following was suggested
    Here's how I fixed it (with homebrew):

```
Install another build of Xcode Tools (typing 'brew update' in the terminal will prompt     you to update the Xcode build tools)
brew update
brew install postgresql
```

but when I do

```
brew install postgresql
```

I get the following:

```
Warning: postgresql-9.3.4 already installed, it's just not linked
```

I can't find a post that covers how to do this. Can someone explain how I'm suppose to link this? or how to the

```
libpq-fe.h header
```

I tried doing

```
brew uninstall postgresql
brew install postgresql
```

which gave me

```
brew uninstall postgresql
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4...


jacks-MacBook-Pro:techendo jsw$ brew install postgresql
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/mach
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql-9.3.4.mavericks.bottle.2.tar.gz
==> Pouring postgresql-9.3.4.mavericks.bottle.2.tar.g
==> Caveats
If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/issue/2510

To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.3) of PostgreSQL, see:
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/upgrading.html

When installing the postgres gem, including ARCHFLAGS is recommended:
  ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg

To install gems without sudo, see the Homebrew wiki.

To have launchd start postgresql at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load postgresql now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/man/man3/SPI_connect.3
/usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link postgresql
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4: 2921 files, 38M
```

It still says it's installed but not linked so I ran

```
brew link postgresql
```

I get the following

```
jacks-MacBook-Pro:techendo jsw$ brew link postgresql
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4... 
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man3/SPI_connect.3
/usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable.
```

It was suggested that I do

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

Which I did

```
jacks-MacBook-Pro:techendo jsw$ ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/jsw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jsw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jsw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jsw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Have you tried uninstall and then reinstalling postgresql?

Comment: @SomeGuy - I just ran brew uninstall postgresql. Then reinstalled it using brew install postgresql. Now when I do brew link postgresql I also get an error. I'm going to update the question.

Comment: That kind of exhausts my big ideas.  Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What worked for me was running:

```
brew doctor
```

I then had to chown a few files and delete a few things it asked me to.

I then ran

```
sudo gem install pg
```

and it worked. Not sure why it only worked with 'sudo' but when I tried before without it failed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the same that this one:

[Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem)

```
brew install postgresql
```