# Installing rails app with sqlite on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku, pg

Hi i am trying to deploy my rails app to heroku using sqlite

reading previous stackoverflow answers
i changed my gemfile as follows
`group :production, :staging do
      gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
  end`

`group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
 end`

but still it is giving error on bundle install
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/Users/akash.bansal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/akash.bansal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in                                                  /Users/akash.bansal/sites/onemustwatch/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/akash.bansal/sites/onemustwatch/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/1.9.1/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Postgres on your local machine in order to run `bundle install`. To do that run `brew install postgresql`. If you don't have Homebrew, you can install it [here](http://brew.sh/)