# Rails error Database pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to run bundle install and i get this error

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My current version of Postgre is  9.3.4

Please suggest I tried other answer but i can't find answer.
I tried to run other commands

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
```

But I got error

```
pg: bundle: No such file or directory
pg: config: Is a directory                                                     
pg: build.pg: No such file or directory
```

I tried solutions of [Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem) but its not solving my problem

I also tried re installing libpq-dev
 getting output

i tried reinstalling

libqp-dev

aditya tiwari [12:07 AM]
and output is like

aditya tiwari [12:07 AM]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
 postgresql-doc-9.4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libpq-dev

```
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/158 kB of archives.
After this operation, 932 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libpq-dev.
(Reading database ... 275104 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpq-dev_9.4.0-1.pgdg12.4+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpq-dev (9.4.0-1.pgdg12.4+1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up libpq-dev (9.4.0-1.pgdg12.4+1) ...
```

Comment: try `bundle config build.pg  --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config`?

Comment: @hd1 its showing You are replacing the current global value of build.pg, which is currently "--with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config"

Comment: @hd1 error is same with replacing pgsql-9.1 by pgsql-9.3

Comment: i have run bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config and now its giving another error see edited text

Comment: Install the dev package. You're missing the libpq-fe.h header file.

Comment: @hd1 I tried apt-file update its showing package i uptodate

Comment: Remove it and reinstall it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68557/discussion-between-hd1-and-aditya-tiwari).

Comment: @mu is too short I cant find answer in link

Comment: @ mu is too short pgsql-9.3.1

Comment: I found answer I was having problem in my Env variable i use command  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/include/postgresql/