# Cannot get postgresql database to find pg_config file

Tags: postgresql, config, pg

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/markhoyt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
sh: /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
 *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

 Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/markhoyt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--enable-windows-cross
--disable-windows-cross
--with-pg-config
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/

 extconf failed, exit code 1

 Gem files will remain installed in    /Users/markhoyt/Desktop/KeyToLife/KeyToLife/KEYTOLIFEPG/KeyToLifeApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1 for inspection.
 Results logged to /Users/markhoyt/Desktop/KeyToLife/KeyToLife/KEYTOLIFEPG/KeyToLifeApp/vendor/bundle    /ruby/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0-static/pg-0.18.1/gem_make.out
```

I have been working on this for two days now and have tried everything I can from stack overflow.  I have installed the PG application, have tried to locate and set up a path with pg config and cannot get it right.

```
 locate pg_config
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/bin/pg_config
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/include/ecpg_config.h
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/include/pg_config.h
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/include/pg_config_ext.h
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/include/pg_config_manual.h
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/include/pg_config_os.h
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/include/server/pg_config.h
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/include/server/pg_config_ext.h
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/include/server/pg_config_manual.h
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/include/server/pg_config_os.h
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/share/man/man1/pg_config.1
/usr/local/bin/pg_config
/usr/local/include/ecpg_config.h
/usr/local/include/pg_config.h
/usr/local/include/pg_config_ext.h
/usr/local/include/pg_config_manual.h
/usr/local/include/pg_config_os.h
/usr/local/share/man/man1/pg_config.1
```

Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6040583/562459

Comment: I have been to this link and tried all answers out and none have worked so hard.  Thank you very much for adding that link though.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running ? Mac ? GNU/Linux ?

If you are running on MacOS a nice alternative is Postgres.app (http://postgresapp.com), it may suit your needs. It's been working flawlessly for me with various frameworks.

Also, I guess you have checked for the header file as well ?
What is the output of : 
    locate libpq-fe.h
?