# Trouble installing the pg gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been having access denied errors when trying to run my first rails app on my mac.

When I run `bundle install` I get

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then I run `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'` and get the following error

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150502-79500-1qqztpf.rb extconf.rb

checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/pg-0.18.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/pg-0.18.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Check out the answers from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem

Comment: Thank you! That was lazy of me. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Are you only running PostgreSQL in production?  In that case make sure it is only grouped for production in your Gemfile:

```
group :production do 
  gem pg, '0.18.1'
end
```

After that, make sure to run bundle install by stating not to install production gems:

```
$ bundle install --without production
```

I hope this helps.