# Bundle install for 'pg' gem endless errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, gemfile, pg

So I'm at the stage of a project where I need to add the 'pg' gem for rails before I can deploy to Heroku, and of course I keep getting error after error. When I first did your basic bundle install I got the errors:

> ERROR:  Error installing pg:
>       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
>   *** extconf.rb failed ***
>
> An error occurred while installing pg (0.21.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.21.0'` succeeds before bundling.

If I try as it suggests with the last sentence, it just repeats the same set of errors.

Hoping there is a simple fix so I can move forward to my next error! Any and all suggestions are appreciated from this newbie developer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find the answer here: 
[Can't install pg gem on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399858/cant-install-pg-gem-on-rails)

> You should probably install the PostgreSQL development libraries.
>
> If you're on Ubuntu this will help:
>
> `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`
>
> On a Mac:
>
> `brew install postgresql`

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your suggestions. When I tried “brew install postgresql” it tells me it is already installed and just not linked. When I tried “brew link postgresql” just now it says: Error: could not symlink share/man/man3/SPI_connect.3/usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable. Which leaves me in a state of staring at me screen.

Comment: Try this:
`sudo chown -R \`whoami\` /usr/local/share/man/ `
end then again:
 `brew link postgresql`

Comment: Hey Patrick, I sincerely thank you for passing that info to me. It worked! Since I am still an underling on here, I can’t vote for it. Hopefully someone else with cred reading this can do it for me. Much appreciated