# Ubuntu and Rails PostgreSQL setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, heroku

I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine. 
I found useful information on how to configure PostgreSQL in Ubuntu for Rails development at [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL), at [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup) and at [digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Putting everything together, all the information seems to converge on the necessity of creating a database superuser with login name that match my Ubuntu user name with: 
 `sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER`

When time arrives to create a password for the new superuser with `sudo -u postgres psql` , I am wondering if Rails can use PostgreSQL without setting the password, if this password can and should be different from my Ubuntu account password and also whether `database.yml` could be a security concern when pushing to Git repository hosting web sites and to Heroku. 
 In`database.yml` in fact is recorded exactly this kind of sensitive information.

[According to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup) it is necessary "to export the DATABASE_URL environment variable for your app to connect to it when running locally", with: `export DATABASE_URL=postgres:///$(whoami)` 
Is that really necessary? At [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) and [digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) this information is not reported.

Finally I am wondering whether the choice of installing PostgreSQL through the PostgreSQL apt repository would be safe enough or it would be preferable to install the LTS version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for Rails to set the connection with a database: via `config/database.yml` or via the environment variable `ENV['DATABASE_URL']`.  See at [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) 
By default `$DATABASE_URL` is empty:

```
echo $DATABASE_URL
```

If posgresql is installed via PostgreSQL apt repository, in order for Rails to use the `pg` gem it is also necessary to install the `libpq-dev` package, otherwise `bundle install` will fail. See [Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem).

From 'man createuser':

```
   createuser creates a new PostgreSQL user (or more precisely, a role). Only superusers and users with
   CREATEROLE privilege can create new users, so createuser must be invoked by someone who can connect as a
   superuser or a user with CREATEROLE privilege.
```

When postgresql is installed, it creates a user `postgres` with role `postgres`. It also creates a `postgres` system account.
So this is why `createuser` should be run as `postgres` user in order to connect to postgresql for the first time and add the user `$USER` (current system user).

It is not necessary to create a password for the new database user. Most people add `database.yml` to their `.gitignore` file so it stays out of version control. It is also possible to use `.pgpass` to keep sensitive 
information out of the *.yml file: see [postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

It is possible to connect to postgresql only as a database user AND through an existing database.
During installation from the postgresql apt repository, postgresql only creates the `postgres` user and the `postgres` database. 
The `psql` command allows the current user to connect to the postgresql database named after the current user. So, if the system user is 'dave' AND there is a 'dave' database it is possible for 'dave' to connect to the 'dave' database with command `psql` with no options. 
If 'dave' is a database user but the database 'dave' was not created, for dave to connect to postgresql it is necessary to specify an existing database with:

```
psql -d postgres
```

Alternatively, it is possible for dave to connect to postgresql executing the `psql` command as the `postgres` user with `sudo`:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```