# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu, rubygems

installed PostgreSQL on my ubuntu system and when i try to run `bundle install` i am getting the following error.

Is there any way to run the command and install all the necessary gems

```
-- gem install pg -v '0.18.4'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/mink7/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext
/home/mink7/usr/local/2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160408-15866-1siay0w.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/mink7/usr/local/2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/mink7/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/pg-0.18.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/mink7/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/mink7/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
```

I have also run

> sudo apt-get install gcc

and made sure the compiler is of the latest version.

Comment: Have you got `libpq-dev` installed?

Comment: Not sure, but this looks like a duplicate of a similar problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem

Answer (score 26):

Look at the message checking for libpq-fe.h... no.

Try installing libpq-dev.
For Ubuntu systems:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Then you should be able to run bundle install.

Comment: If you use Alpine linux (Docker image in my case), you should install postgresql-dev instead.
`apk add postgresql-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error but with below message:

> checking for pg_config... no

So as per above solution I ran as below:

```
dnf install libpq-dev   (Since I am using Fedora 23)
```

But got this messsage:

> No package libpq-dev available. Error: Unable to find a match.

Initially postgresql was installed with below command:

```
dnf install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
```

And when I did `which pg_config`, I got this:

> /usr/bin/which: **no pg_config** in
>   (/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/mayur/.local/bin:/home/mayur/bin)

So I installed postgresql again with this command:

```
dnf install postgresql-devel
```

Now on running `which pg_config`, output `/usr/bin/pg_config`.

Then try `bundle install`:

**Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions...without any error.**