# PostgreSQL ruby gem installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have some troubles with installing my Postgres gem. When I run:

```
 gem install pg -v '0.19.0'
```

it prints:

```
Successfully installed pg-0.19.0
Parsing documentation for pg-0.19.0
Done installing documentation for pg after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but when I run:

```
bundle install
```

it stops on the pg gem and prints:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.19.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.19.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The whole log is:

```
sh: /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.   You may need configuration options.
```

`gem env` outputs:

```
/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/environment_command.rb:154: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
     - /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
     - /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin
     - /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin
     - /.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem)

Comment: which OS are you using??

Comment: @adil Mac OS Sierra

Comment: Are you using `gem install` or `sudo gem install`? What does `gem env` output?

Comment: @theTinMan gem install, without `sudo`. Which exactly line interests you un `gem env`?

Comment: All of `gem env` interests us. It helps us determine whether gem is happy with its world.

Comment: @theTinMan I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that gem installed pg without it knowing where your PostgreSQL is installed.

The error messages

```
sh: /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
```

are the result of the code not being able to locate the headers, which are the result of not finding `pg_config`.

The simple fix is to temporarily update your PATH with the directory containing `pg_config`. You can do that easily using `locate`:

```
locate pg_config
```

On my system that returns:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/pg_config
```

among other things. The `pg_config` you want will be in the `bin` directory for whichever PostgreSQL you want to use with Ruby.

If you don't have `locate` running you could also do:

```
find / -name pg_config -type f 2>/dev/null
```

and wait while `find` searches your drive. (Having `locate` available to you is very helpful, so if it's not running I'd suggest starting it.)

Modify your PATH with the path to `pg_config` then run your commands:

```
PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin:$PATH gem install pg && bundle install
```

Modify the path to pg_config for your system of course.

It *might* also work to remove `gem install pg &&` and simply run the `bundle install`.

Comment: where to write my PATH? In `.bashrc`?

Comment: `Modify your PATH` where I need to modify it? In .bashrc or? In which file?

Comment: Did you try what I said? Put it all on the same line in the terminal and execute it.

Comment: Does `locate pg_config` return the location of `pg_config` on your system?

Comment: I used `find / -name pg_config -type f 2>/dev/null` and it returned me the same output as you have