# Installing Postgres gem on Rails 5.2 throws error – Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, vagrant

I'm trying to set up a Rails project with Vagrant. Using Rails 5.2 as well.

In my original `bundle install`, it told me

```
Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:

      bundle install --path vendor/bundle

  to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
  and install the bundled gems to RubyGems using sudo.
```

...So I tried that and got:

```
Fetching pg 1.0.0
Installing pg 1.0.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pg-1.0.0/ext
/usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180501-2212-1algyv4.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/pg-1.0.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/pg-1.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/pg-1.0.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Looking at the log file mentioned has this in it:

```
find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- no

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I.    -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -E -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I.    -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */
```

Unclear how to proceed and get this working. Would love some help or advice. Thanks!

**Edit:**

I run `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` and then get an error related to and old version.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /tmp/bundler20180501-4263-lecb9zpg-1.0.0/gems/pg-1.0.0/ext
/usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180501-4263-1qowxi6.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... no
Your PostgreSQL is too old. Either install an older version of this gem or upgrade your database to at least PostgreSQL-9.2.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Comment: try gem uninstall pg and then install again

Comment: It's not technically installed, so I can't uninstall it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem)