# PostgreSQL gem failing in bundle install for Rails on CentOS 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, centos

I've been all over trying all sorts of solutions so I'd appreciate any help.

I have the following PostgreSQL items installed:

```
postgresql96.x86_64 - 9.6.12-1PGDG.rhel6
postgresql96-devel.x86_64 - 9.6.12-1PGDG.rhel6
postgresql96-libs.x86_64 - 9.6.12-1PGDG.rhel6
postgresql96-server.x86_64 - 9.6.12-1PGDG.rhel6
```

When I run `bundle install`, I get the following error:

```
Installing pg 1.1.4 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: 
/home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/ext
/home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/ruby -I 
/home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190502-8579-10nqtt0.rb extconf.rb
--with-pg-config\=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config
sh: /opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
sh: /opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

A large majority of the guides say that we need to install the `devel` and `libs` packages but they are already installed. I am using CentOS 6.

Thanks!

Also I should add that I'm using yum as my package manager, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `gem install pg -v 1.1.4` yet and see if the same error shows up? Also, you might `bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config` after confirming that your pg_config actually lives there

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you need the postgres client tools also... when compiling postgres on the server. You should install the devel packages for postgres server and the command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for CentOS `libpq-fe.h` header comes with `postgresql-devel`:

```
yum install postgresql-devel
```

Ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/6040822/4950680