# Installing Ruby on Rails latest version matching Ruby 3.0

Tags: ruby

When I try the following, after installing Ruby 3.0 from snap on Ubuntu 18.04::

```
gem install rails
```

I get this error:

```
/snap/ruby/201/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb:13:in `<module:RbConfig>': ruby lib version (3.0.0) doesn't match executable version (2.5.1) (RuntimeError)
```

It was right after using

```
rails new rest-api-messages --api --database=postgresql
```

and trying to install PostGRES

```
gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

How could I solve this? is Ruby on Rails only for version 2.5.1 and lower?

---

edit: Then I got

```
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem
```

Solved with

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Duplicate from [Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you already had Ruby 2.5 installed and they are stepping on each other. Ruby versions don't overwrite each other. You need to uninstall Ruby 3.0 and 2.5 and install a Ruby version manager then install Ruby using it. This will also give you a path to move forward easily.  Check out Ruby version manager like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/). Take a look at both. For what it's worth. I have used both and finally settled on rbenv.

Comment: I had it installed with apt-get and then removed it

Comment: There is a version of ruby already install on Ubuntu. It has to be removed first.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove gem` have done this but now I get `mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h` when trying to install pg with gem

Comment: Also, I would not be installing Ruby from snaps. Use one of the Ruby version managers to install the version you need.

Comment: Run Ruby -v and see what happens. If you get an answer you still have a version installed.

Comment: If not... Then install one of the Ruby Version managers, then use it to install Ruby 3.0

Comment: Here is a step-through article on how to do it. 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: it worked to install cleanly ruby and rails with latest version changed to 3.0.0 and 6.1.3 but still get the error for postgresql: missing `fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Edit: its a duplicate, vote to close, appreciate the help though! Thanks Mike!